# Unable to get the subscription working with google-mirror-api

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm using the sample Java app. I send myself a card that has the "Reply" action. I reply from my Glass using my voice, but I don't get the notification. I have to refresh the page to see the reply.

I've setup the reverse proxy 'grok' to get the notifications.

On starting the app, I see this in the logs:
**INFO: Attempting to subscribe verify_token 68840674215 with callback https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://xyz.ngrok.com/notify**

If I make a POST request from a REST client to notify-url , the NotifyServlet.doPost() is correctly invoked.

In the insertSubscription(Credential credential, String callbackUrl, String userId, String collection) method of MirrorClient, I have hardcoded callbackUrl = "https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://xyz.ngrok.com/notify";

On the Google API console, I have added the URIs to "Javascript Origins" and to "Redirect URIs"

Can someone please tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ngrok as a proxy, use **https**://xyz.ngrok.com/notify as the callback URL instead of having mirrornotifications.appspot.com forward the request.The NotifyServlet will be invoked when the "Reply" action is performed.